# A function that returns a digit within a number

Tags: c++, c

I want to create a function which will a number and the position of the digit that I want to retrieve,

```
int getDigit(int value, int positionFromLeft)
```

Say, getDigit(534, 2) will return 3.

What could be the easiest / efficient way to write this function?

Comment: pushing digit by digit in a vector, and indexing out when required.

Comment: I think @Cameron meant 'show us the code'

Comment: If you manage to get a multi-language source file, please post it. Anyway, I suggest you stick to one single language per file: either `C` or `C++` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All these string-based solutions scare me... Really guys? :-/

```
int getDigit(int value, int positionFromLeft)
{
    int posFromRight = 1;
    {
        int v = value;
        while (v /= 10)
            ++posFromRight;
    }
    posFromRight -= positionFromLeft - 1;
    while (--posFromRight)
        value /= 10;
    value %= 10;
    return value > 0 ? value : -value;
}
```

Note that passing an out-of-bounds value for `positionFromLeft` won't return any sensical value as-is.

Comment: Finally a simple solution. Cheers!

Comment: Your `getDigit(1234567, 2)` returns 5 not 3.  It just so happens that with 534, the 3 is second from left and second from right.

Comment: Yeah, except that your solution is wrong. Wrong as in left does not equal right! The question specifies `positionFromLeft`, i.e. if you pass 1 you want the most significant digit, but you are returning the least significant.

Comment: -1 the string-based solutions are because you solved an easier problem than OP's question, and did not answer OP's question.

Comment: In that case you asked the wrong question and wasted our time... Because this answer definitely does not solve your problem as it was asked.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, @bitmask, @R.. : Yep, edited. Too tired to read properly

Comment: @R.. sorry, I tried the opposite way, when I was testing it again. :(

Comment: It is still incorrect for negative values and out-of-bounds positions.

Comment: @hammar : And what exactly is "correct" for out-of-bounds positions?

Comment: @ildjarn: Well, that depends. I've opted to throw an exception in my example. In C, I guess returning -1 might be acceptable. Leaving it undefined is arguably a valid choice, but in my opinion not a very user-friendly one.

Comment: @hammar : Given that it's homework, and the expected behavior wasn't specified, I'll gladly leave that as an exercise for the student.

Comment: @ildjarn: Sure, but you might want to document it at the very least :)

Answer (score 6):

First, it'll be a *lot* easier if you're willing to work for the right instead of the left (i.e., from the least significant digit).

Given an input N, `N%10` will give the least significant digit. X/10 will shift X one digit to the right, x/100 will shift it two digits to the right, etc.

If you really need to start from the left, `log10` should get you the total number of digits.

Comment: Well, yes - if you change the question, it is a lot easier to come up with an answer!

Comment: @Johathan: yes, but I answered the question as asked as well. I'd note that where he specifies the digits as starting from the left is prefaced with "Say", which normally signifies that it's a possible example, not necessarily the only possibility.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is just to convert to a string and do a lookup. This example uses C++, but the idea can easily be translated to C.

```
int getDigit(int value, int positionFromLeft) {
    if (value < 0) positionFromLeft++;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << value;

    std::string s = ss.str();
    if (positionFromLeft >= 1 && positionFromLeft <= s.length())
        return s[positionFromLeft-1] - '0';
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("invalid digit position");
}
```

Turns out there are some corner cases to think about here.

- What happens if `value` is negative? I chose to ignore the sign and count from the first digit.
- What if the position is out of bounds? I chose to throw an exception.
- There is also a possibility of `value` being `INT_MIN`, so simply taking the absolute value won't work.

Comment: This is somewhat I tried, but I used a vector instead. This ss << value, line makes things much cleaner. :) thank you!

Comment: This is not a bilingual solution and the question is tagged bilingually.

Comment: @Jonathan: Ah, I missed the C tag. I've added a note about it being C++ only.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler C and C++ shouldn't be tagged in the same question. Therefore who cares.

Answer (score 1):

Different recursive solution to this old question (I changed the type of `positionFromLeft` to `unsigned`)

```
int getDigit(int value, unsigned positionFromLeft) {
    assert(positionFromLeft > 0);
    if (positionFromLeft == 1) return abs(value) % 10;
    if (value == 0) return 0; // optimization: break out of recursion if 0 is reached
    return getDigit(value / 10, positionFromLeft - 1);
}
```

See [ideone](https://ideone.com/nZj5k6)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest but not necessarily the best:

```
int getDigit(int value, int positionFromLeft)
{
    char buf[sizeof(int)*3+2];
    if (sprintf(buf, "%d", value)-1U < positionFromLeft-1U) return -1;
    return buf[positionFromLeft-1U]-'0';
}
```

**Note:** Edited since someone objected (apparently) to `snprintf` not being in C++, and to account for out-of-bounds and one-based position. Now it's slightly less simple...

Comment: But note this is not valid C++.

Comment: @aschepler: why do you assert that?  Because it uses `snprintf()` which is not in standard C++?  Or for some other reason?

Comment: You have minor buffer management problems if `positionFromLeft` is negative or if the number is so short that there isn't an Nth digit.  Also, for the example, you return 4 instead of 3 (off-by-one), but you get the right answer for `getDigit(-534,2)` which I don't (yet).

Comment: But the sizeof(int)*3+2 was neat :)

Comment: Oops, never mind.  My brain somehow thought there was a variable in the array bound for `buf`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDigit(original,nonZeroIndexedIndex)
{
    return ((int)floor(original / pow(10, nonZeroIndexedIndex))) % 10;
}
```

with @R..'s suggestion:

```
function getDigit(original,nonZeroIndexedIndex)
{
    int tens [5] = { 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000 };
    return ((int)floor(original / tens[nonZeroIndexedIndex - 1])) % 10;
}
```

Hope this helps! This is a nice little C++ refresher for me :)

Comment: oh! oops! thanks for callin me out on that. It's been a while since I've written a line of C++ :)

Comment: `pow` is not reliable for integer use. Simply use a `static const` array of the powers of 10. There aren't many.

Comment: Regardless of the fact that this is the wrong way around, you do not need the floor, nor any floating point here. C++, as C, always floor integer divisions.

Comment: What type is `function`?  And what are the types of the arguments to the function?  This is not C++; it might be C89 if there is a `typedef int function;` in scope, but it is using obsolescent features of C89.

Answer (score 0):

```
int getDigit(int value, int positionFromLeft)
{
    char buffer[20];
    if (value > 0)
        value = -value;
    int len = snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d", value);
    int digit = 0;
    if (len > positionFromLeft && positionFromLeft > 0)
        digit = buffer[positionFromLeft] - '0';
    return digit;
}
```

This returns zero if you ask for a digit beyond the RHS of the number.  The negation trick ensures that the value is always negative (and never runs into problems with negating INT_MIN), and then there is a minus sign so the `positionFromLeft` is correct without adjusting by one.  This code assumes C99 or C++ (with the minor caveat that `snprintf()` is not mandated by C++98 but is likely to be available as an extension; a pure C++98 and C99 solution would have to use `sprintf()` instead, which in context is safe enough).

#### Protest over the solution that was at one time selected as correct!

Consider the test harness:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getDigit1(int value, int positionFromLeft)
{
    while (--positionFromLeft)
        value /= 10;
    return value % 10;
}

int getDigit2(int value, int positionFromLeft)
{
    char buffer[20];
    if (value > 0)
        value = -value;
    int len = snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d", value);
    int digit = 0;
    if (len > positionFromLeft && positionFromLeft > 0)
        digit = buffer[positionFromLeft] - '0';
    return digit;
}

int main(void)
{
    int values[] = { 534, 1234567, -1234567 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++)
            printf("getDigit(%d, %d) = (v1) %d, (v2) %d\n", values[i], j,
                   getDigit1(values[i], j), getDigit2(values[i], j));
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This solution produces the correct value for `getDigit(534, 2)` and `getDigit(1234567, 4)` (and, generally, the middle digit of a number that has an odd number of digits) but is otherwise incorrect:

```
getDigit(534, 1) = (v1) 4, (v2) 5
getDigit(534, 2) = (v1) 3, (v2) 3
getDigit(534, 3) = (v1) 5, (v2) 4
getDigit(534, 4) = (v1) 0, (v2) 0
getDigit(534, 5) = (v1) 0, (v2) 0
getDigit(534, 6) = (v1) 0, (v2) 0
getDigit(534, 7) = (v1) 0, (v2) 0

getDigit(1234567, 1) = (v1) 7, (v2) 1
getDigit(1234567, 2) = (v1) 6, (v2) 2
getDigit(1234567, 3) = (v1) 5, (v2) 3
getDigit(1234567, 4) = (v1) 4, (v2) 4
getDigit(1234567, 5) = (v1) 3, (v2) 5
getDigit(1234567, 6) = (v1) 2, (v2) 6
getDigit(1234567, 7) = (v1) 1, (v2) 7

getDigit(-1234567, 1) = (v1) -7, (v2) 1
getDigit(-1234567, 2) = (v1) -6, (v2) 2
getDigit(-1234567, 3) = (v1) -5, (v2) 3
getDigit(-1234567, 4) = (v1) -4, (v2) 4
getDigit(-1234567, 5) = (v1) -3, (v2) 5
getDigit(-1234567, 6) = (v1) -2, (v2) 6
getDigit(-1234567, 7) = (v1) -1, (v2) 7
```

The question specifically asks for the Nth digit from the LEFT of the number, counting from 1.

Comment: Your test for negative value is backwards.

Comment: @hammar?  It is?  I want to ensure that the value is negative before I format it.  There were two errors - one syntactic, one off-by-one when I changed the logic, but the sign inversion is correct.

Comment: @Jonathan: From the off-by-one it seemed like you wanted a positive value. But this way it also dodges the case for INT_MIN, which my code  initially failed on. Getting these things right sure can be tricky, huh? :)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler : Of course, while you were busy typing out your protest, the answer in question was remedied... ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn: yes - which is why I carefully identified it as 'at one time'...your current version does not like getDigit(534, 4) and goes into an infinite loop (or, at least, loop that lasts multiple seconds) when asked to return the 4th digit of a 3-digit number.  Otherwise, it produces correct results, though.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler : Sure, which is why I gave the explicit caveat about passing out-of-bounds values. If getting a nonsensical value sooner is considered "better" than getting a nonsensical value later, then changing `while (--posFromRight)` to `while (--posFromRight > 0)` should do the trick.

Comment: @ildjarn: unless you already know how many digits the source number has, it is hard to make it bullet-proof.  My code returns 0; I'd accept -1 as possibly (even probably) better.  But locking up the machine is not going to be popular - it is a very bad way of reporting invalid inputs.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler : This is C++, I'm fine with calling it UB ;-]

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to count from left, you can do this:

```
uint8_t getDigitR(uint16_t value, uint8_t i) {
  uint32_t digit = 1;
  while (digit <= value)
    digit *= 10;
  while (i--) // if you start counting at 1
    digit /= 10;
  return (value / digit) % 10;
}
```

But this is probably not really more efficient or easier than string solutions, but since it is homework, there might be a few algebraic things to learn if not done with strings :)

However, you need less stack space.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be different, one with no `#include` needed.

```
int getDigit(unsigned int original, unsigned int positionFromLeft)
{
    if (original==0 && positionFromLeft==1) {
        /* In a more mathematical world, zero has no digits. */
        return 0;
    }
    unsigned int expon=0;
    unsigned int power=1;
    for (unsigned int quotient=original; quotient; quotient/=10, ++expon) {
        if (expon >= positionFromLeft) {
            power *= 10;
        }
    }
    if (positionFromLeft > expon) {
        /* Not enough digits in number. */
        return -1;
    }
    return (original / power) % 10;
}
```

Comment: I tried it in my test harness - see my answer - and got getDigit(534, 3) = -1, and getDigit(1234567, 7) = -1; the other values were correct.  You probably need '>' instead of '>=' in the 'not enough digits' test.

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks. Fixed. Clearly I should have done more unit testing.

Comment: You might care to test negative numbers...getDigit(-1234567, x) is interesting.

Comment: I changed the parameter types to unsigned on purpose.  Or of course, you could do like some solutions and rectify all input to non-negative as a first step.

Comment: One argument says 'the problem asked for `int` not `unsigned int`', but that does 'fix' the negative value problem (though negative numbers do have an Nth digit from the left).  Negating INT_MIN to a positive number requires the use of an integer type bigger than `int` (on a 2's complement machine).  Negating INT_MAX to a negative number works fine on 1's complement, 2's complement and sign-magnitude machines.

Comment: I get -1 from getDigit(0, 1)?  :(

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i am wrong.

You can try using sprintf to cast the int to a string representations.
Then have a pointer (say *ptr) point to the first position.

Let positionFromLeft be the position of the character that you want to extract.

Using,

***(ptr + positionFromLeft)**

will give you the required digit.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the easiest solution:

```
   int valuePosition(int value, int position) {
     int r;
     for(int i=0; i<=position; i++){
       r = value % 10;
       value = value / 10;
     }
     return r;
   }
```

The first position is 0, if you want that starts in 1 change i<=position with 1

Answer (score 0):

Add to the Number class an instance method called getDigit with the following signature:
int getDigit (int digitNum)
When the digitNum variable specifies the digit number (0) for the unity series, 1 for the tens digit
And so on. The method will return the appropriate digit if such a digit exists. Otherwise the method will return
.-1
.-1 will return digitNum = 6 and for 4 return the digitNN = 3 method for: value = 124571 if, to

List item